# Have net ads join create a PTR record

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory

When using the `net ads join` command to join a Linux host (CentOS 6.5) to a domain (Windows Server 2008 DCs), an A record is created but not a corresponding PTR record.  Is it possible to have the PTR record created automatically?  Perhaps a parameter to `net ads join` or a setting in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`?

FYI the full command I run to join a host to the DC:

```
sudo net ads join createcomputer="machines/Servers/Linux Servers" osName="CentOS" osVer=6.5 -U banjer
```

When creating a DNS A record manually on the Windows Server the PTR record is created automatically.  Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: Does `/usr/local/samba/sbin/samba_dnsupdate` create the PTR record properly?

Comment: I don't seem to have the `samba_dnsupdate` command on CentOS.  I did `sudo locate samba_dnsupdate` and `sudo yum provides *samba_dnsupdate*` but no luck.  I'll see what it does exactly and perhaps I can build it.

Comment: I am having this exact same issue on CentOS and it is surprisingly hard to find any answers. Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that `nsupdate` can be used as a workaround to create a PTR record from the Linux side:

```
banjer@myhost~> nsupdate
> update add 210.31.20.192.in-addr.arpa 3600 ptr myhost.example.com.
> send
```

That same command as a one-liner:

```
echo -e "update add 210.31.20.192.in-addr.arpa 3600 ptr myhost.example.com.\nsend" | nsupdate
```

Where 210.31.20.192 is your IP in reverse order.

I'm open to a better answer for getting net ads to add the PTR record properly though.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a primary reverse lookup zone for that network then windows server can automatically create the necessary PTR records when you add a A(AAA) host record in your primary forward lookup zones.